# XPath как получить несколько элементов?

Tags: html, парсер, xml, xpath

Не могу получить xpath для element 1 и element 3.
Хотелось получить все содержимое только div класса element1 и element3.
Структура страницы выглядит примерно так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что пробовали? ваши варианты?

Comment: Задавая вопрос, вы должны предоставить **минимальный воспроизводимый пример**:
(1) Входной XML.
(2) Ваша логика и XPath, который пытается ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе № 1 выше. картинок не надо, только текст.